# NextJS getServerSideProps() with multiple fetch requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to fetch data from multiple API routes in a single `getServerSideProps()`?

I have a table that I need to show data from multiple MongoDB collections and trying to figure out how to pull that data in.

Essentially, I need to combine these two functions but can't seem to find the best way to go about it.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute}`);
  const { data } = await res.json();
  return { props: { operations: data } };
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute2}`);
  const { data } = await res.json();
  return { props: { incidents: data } };
}
```

I may be attempting something dumb so a pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const [operationsRes, incidentsRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute}`), 
    fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute2}`)
  ]);
  const [operations, incidents] = await Promise.all([
    operationsRes.json(), 
    incidentsRes.json()
  ]);
  return { props: { operations, incidents } };
}
```

`Promise.all` will trigger both requests and they will return the resolved value for both fetch calls when completed

Comment: That did it, thank you for the quick answer! I'm still fairly new to this and I see I'll have to look more into Promises.

Comment: The same pattern I m using but it's slow down the page performance.

Comment: How well are the APIs performing? I think that this pattern is way better than executing them sequentially

Comment: Helped me clean my code lines. Thank you!