# NextJS run in a Docker container doesn't recgonize custom React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, next.js

#### What am I trying to do?

I'm running a next app in docker and try to use custom hooks to fetch data from an API

My hook looks like this:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
import { useState } from "react"
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default async function useAuth() {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const { response: authentication, error, request } = useFetch(
    "https://api.company.io/oauth/token",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        audience: "https://api.company.com/"
      })
    }
  );

  if (fetching) {
    await request();
    setFetching(false)
  }

  if (!error) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authentication));
  }

  return { error };
}
```

I call this hook in the getServerSideProps function of Nextjs

Index.tsx

```
// imports

const Home: React.FC = () => {

  const res = useUserData()
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({})

  const onSubmit = () => {
    setProfile(res)
    console.log(res)
  }


return(
  <Phone>
      // Form
      
          <Button href="/live" text="Start!" handleClick={() => onSubmit()} />

      // Closing tags
    </Phone>
)
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = useAuth().then(res => console.log(res.json()))
                        .catch(error => console.log(error))
  
  return {
    props: {}
  }
}

export default Home
```

And I have a custom webpack config

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            issuer: {
                test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
            },
        });
        
        return config;
    },
    webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
        config.watchOptions = {
            poll: 1000, // Check for changes every second
            aggregateTimeout: 300 // delay before rebuilding
        };
        return config;
    },
    distDir: ".next",
    sassOptions: {
        additionalData: '@forward "styles/colors";'
    },
};
```

#### What happens?

I get this error - I've included the whole docker-compose up log

```
Recreating app ... done
Attaching to app
app    | yarn install v1.22.5
app    | [1/4] Resolving packages...
app    | success Already up-to-date.
app    | Done in 0.58s.
app    | yarn run v1.22.5
app    | $ next dev -p 8080
app    | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:8080, url: http://localhost:8080
app    | info  - Loaded env from /usr/app/.env
app    | info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
app    | event - compiled successfully
app    | event - build page: /
app    | wait  - compiling...
app    | event - compiled successfully
app    | Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:     
app    | 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such 
as React DOM)
app    | 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
app    | 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
app    | See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
app    |     at resolveDispatcher (/usr/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476:13)
app    |     at useState (/usr/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1507:20)
app    |     at useAuth (webpack-internal:///./utilities/hooks/useAuth.ts:13:61)app    |     at getServerSideProps (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:100:86)
app    |     at renderToHTML (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:40:221)
app    |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
app    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)app    |     at async /usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:112:97
app    |     at async /usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:105:142
app    |     at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:137:387)
app    |     at async DevServer.renderToHTML (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:138:610)
app    |     at async DevServer.renderToHTML (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:36:578)
app    |     at async DevServer.render (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:75:160)
app    |     at async Object.fn (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:58:672)
app    |     at async Router.execute (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:25:67)
app    |     at async DevServer.run (/usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:68:1042)
```

#### What have I tried?

I want to say everything, but that's not clear enough so here's a short list:

- Deleted node_modules and .next
- Changed webpack config in multiple ways (WithTM, set aliases, set externals, etc.
- Tried to do a check to see if there are multiple React instances, but I only get errors saying 'React2 does not exist on instance of
  window'
- Tried running it locally instead of in a container

I think I've tried every option in [this thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9022) and [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991), but I'm still receiving the same error, anyone here that can help?

Comment: Can you pubish the source of the project?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue further?  Editing the question to include a [mcve] and explaining what behavior you're seeing would be helpful.  Make sure to include enough relevant code as text (not an image) and directly in the question (not behind a link) so someone looking at the question has enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've updated the post and included any code I think is relevant, if antything is missing, let me know!

Comment: @Oleg unfortunately not, due to privacy issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not use hooks in getServerSideProps.
You can use this method for fetching:
[NextJS getServerSideProps() with multiple fetch requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546154/nextjs-getserversideprops-with-multiple-fetch-requests)

Comment: I don't think the problem lies here. I do believe it's not possible in the getServerSideProps, so that's one thing to fix, but I can't use hooks anywhere in my code. I can update the question with another example?

Comment: My answer is based on code that you published. Fix it and see if you have some other errors.

Comment: I fixed it, but as I mentioned my other hooks aren't working either. I'm stuck with the same error, only on a different hook now, I can update the post, but I think it will get too long

Comment: If you need a help please  post the other errors and code. I think you have something similar....

Comment: I've updated the issue, thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Did you update the error stack? For now according to posted  error you have issue  in ./pages/index.tsx:100:86) and hook in getServersSideProps.

Comment: I've made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659094/nextjs-doesnt-recgonize-custom-hooks) and updated the above to be the original question, for clarity